# Magento Contact Form: Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-form

When visitors to our website try to fill in our contact form on our contact page, they are sent to `/contact/index`, and receive the error `Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later`.

At Magento Configuration, I see:
[image]

If I change `Enable` to Yes, I see a different form, which doesn't work.

I can't change it back to No now - it is stuck on Yes.

Web hosting support say:

> No errors are being generated and saved to server logs. I can
>   see that any issue that exists occurs in the contact form application
>   itself, as the mail server never receives any request to send email
>   from it.
>
> Access logs showing contact form usage:
>   185.93.231.8 - - [27/Nov/2017:09:42:39 +1100] "POST /contacts/index/post/ HTTP/1.1" 302 606
>   "http://example.com/contacts/index/" "Mozilla/5.0
>   (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"

I'd really appreciate some suggestions on how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: have you configure email setting in admin end?

Comment: How do I do this please @Abdul ?

Answer (score 1):

This error usually comes because of the **server** which **has not configured for sending email**. If you check `var/log/exception.log`, you will see this error `Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception: Unable to send mail. mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver .......`  .